# Error validating datasource `db`: the URL must start with the protocol `prisma://`

Tags: database, mongodb, next.js, prisma, next-auth

Iam working on a nextjs 14 project using nextAuth and mongodb in the database
Iam trying to create new user in sign up page
this is my sign up action :

```
'use server';

import bcrypt from 'bcryptjs';

import { db } from '@/lib/db';
import { SignUpSchema, SignUpSchemaType } from '@/schemas/auth';
import { getUserByEmail } from '@/data/user';

export async function signup(data: SignUpSchemaType) {
  const validateFields = SignUpSchema.safeParse(data);

  if (!validateFields.success) {
    return { error: 'Invalid fields!' };
  }

  const { username, email, password } = validateFields.data;
  const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10);

  try {
    const existingUser = await getUserByEmail(email);
    if (existingUser) return { error: 'Email already in use!' };

    await db.user.create({
      data: {
        username,
        email,
        password: hashedPassword,
      },
    });


    return { success: 'Sign Up Success!' };
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error.code === 11000) {
      return { error: 'This username already in use!' };
    } else {
      throw new Error(`Failed: ${error.message}`);
    }
  }
}
```

and this is my prisma schema

```
datasource db {
  provider = "mongodb"
  url      = env("DATABASE_URL")
}

generator client {
  provider = "prisma-client-js"
}

enum Gender {
  male
  female
  unspecified
}

model User {
  id         String    @id @default(auto()) @map("_id") @db.ObjectId
  username   String    @unique()
  name       String?
  email      String    @unique()
  image      String?   @default("default.jpg")
  password   String
  gender     Gender?   @default(unspecified)
  birthday   DateTime? @db.Date
  bio        String?
  dateJoined DateTime? @db.Date
  Account    Account[]
}

model Account {
  id                String  @id @default(cuid()) @map("_id")
  userId            String  @db.ObjectId
  type              String
  provider          String
  providerAccountId String
  refresh_token     String?
  access_token      String?
  expires_at        Int?
  token_type        String?
  scope             String?
  id_token          String?
  session_state     String?

  user User @relation(fields: [userId], references: [id], onDelete: Cascade)

  @@unique([provider, providerAccountId])
}
```

and my DATABASE_URL in .env looks something like this
DATABASE_URL=mongodb+srv://username:password@host:port/friends?retryWrites=true&w=majority

what is causing the issue here
can anyone help me on this i'm stuck for almost a day

This is the error am encoutering :

Unhandled Runtime Error
Error: Failed:
Invalid `prisma.user.create()` invocation:

Error validating datasource `db`: the URL must start with the protocol `prisma://`

```
Source
actions\signup.ts (37:12) @ signup

  35 |     return { error: 'This username already in use!' };
  36 |   } else {
> 37 |     throw new Error(`Failed: ${error.message}`);
     |          ^
  38 |   }
  39 | }
  40 | }
```

i tried to delete node_modules and reinstall them but didn't worked for me